# Is this usage of "indeed" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

*Likewise, neurons’ distance relative to the electrical field affects their response to stimulation, and neurons in deep cortical layers were often inhibited by anodal and excited by cathodal stimulation, **indeed***, neurons in deep cortical layers were often inhibited by anodal and excited by cathodal stimulation

Comment: It looks like part of the next clause.

Comment: --Likewise, neurons’ distance relative to the electrical field affects their response to stimulation, indeed, neurons in deep cortical layers were often inhibited by anodal and excited by cathodal stimulation-- is this better?

Comment: It would help for you to add to the question (use the [edit] link) some information about what you're trying to say, and why you want to use the word *indeed* to say it.

Comment: Even if it is grammatically correct, it adds nothing to an already complex sentence. Get rid of it.

Comment: It's definitely not a correct usage as it stands. "Indeed" can be used to stress the level of something, as in "His hair was very wet indeed", where "indeed" stresses "very". But in your example there is no gradable modifier which can be stressed.

Comment: Note that no reputable English scientific journal would accept "neurons'". For the possessive of inanimate objects it is always "of the neurons".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as the start of a new sentence:

> . Indeed, …

or after a conjunction if preceded by a shorter clause:

> , and indeed …

if used in the way explained by [The Oxford Dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indeed) :

> Used to emphasize a statement or response confirming something already
>   suggested.
>
> ‘it was not expected to last long, and indeed it took less
>   than three weeks’

But I have been told that this is British English usage, so it may appear strange to North Americans.

However the example cited in the question seems to be repeating the same material, so it neither works nor would survive refereeing by a reputable scientific journal.

(Nor would “neurons’”, as I mention in my comment.)

Answer (score 1):

It only really works if there is something to say 'indeed' about as 'indeed' is an expression that affirms agreement - you would need a sentence before, which the 'indeed' could be agreeing with. It doesn't really make sense here on its own. And as the sentence begins 'likewise' this indicates that something was said before, to which this sentence is referring.

So, I suggest you go find the preceding sentence in order to really see the meaning.

And the following sentence, would probably help, as well...